# Unwanted space inside div set to 100%

Tags: internet-explorer, html

EDIT:
This seems to be a problem with IE exclusively. Very simple to re-create, and it occurs regardless of what height (px or %) I set the DIV to.

So I have a page with a 100% width and height div. everything works fine except in IE, where it shows about 5px of unwanted space inside the div at the very bottom, which is annoying because when you scroll to the bottom of the div, you see it.

Can somebody explain to me what is going on here?

If i just remove the div and use the normal body tag for scrolling, the space disappears.

To re-create this, here is the code:

```
<html><body style='width:100%;height:100%;margin:0px;padding:0px;overflow:hidden;'>
<div style='width:100%;height:100%;margin:0px;padding:0px;overflow:auto;'>
<br />...x100
Are you kidding me IE?
</div></html>
```

and that's it. Don't know who voted this down, but come on this is literally the easiest code to re-create what-so-ever.

I've also tried adding
    position:absolute;bottom:0px;left:0px;
to the div, no difference.

Comment: can you post some code? have you done a *{margin 0;padding:0} at the start of your css?

Comment: Yes I have html, body {width:100%;height:100%;margin:0px;padding:0px;} as well as on the div itself, which has overflow auto. Also, body has overflow hidden.

Comment: Code sample needed or a link.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I used an HTML file with this source code:

```
<html>
   <body style='width:100%;height:100%;margin:0px;padding:0px;overflow:hidden;'>
      <div style='width:100%;height:100%;margin:0px;padding:0px;overflow:auto;'>
         <br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>
         <br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>
         <br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>
         <br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>
         <br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>
         <br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>
         <br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>
         <br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>
         <br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>
         <br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>
         Are you kidding me IE?
      </div>
   </body>
</html>
```

I opened the file in IE and set the display mode to IE7.

I was not able to reproduce your issue...

Comment: @RyanStortz According to your own code, it is *not* block-level, but inline-level (the DIV directly contains text).

Comment: I would appreciate that. I have never heard of such a problem before.

Comment: @RyanStortz I am not able to reproduce your issue. See my answer. Could you copy-paste the code from my answer and try for yourself?

Comment: I got it to work using what you told me, it turns out I had a spacer image that i had forgotten about, which was inline. Thanks1

Comment: @RyanStortz Note that you want to start your file with `<!doctype html>`, if you're not doing that already. Otherwise, the browser will render the page in quirks more, instead of standards mode.

Answer (score 0):

Is this an asp page? If so, look into removing skiplinks (or setting it to empty string). They tend to place unwanted space when rendered in browsers other than IE